# My asp.net website is trying to connect mysql db though I am not using mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server

My ASP.net web form website is using MSSQL server and site web.cofig has sql server connection string. But I am surprised that why it is trying to connect my sql db though there is no connection string for my sql.

Comment: Please share code

Comment: How do you know it is doing that? What are the symptoms? Have you debugged your application to see where you think this is happening? Without some relevant code and a better description of the situation there's not much anyone can do to help you. There's not just a magic generic answer to this

Comment: After adding application_error() under global.asax              
     protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();                                                     
        }

Comment: Please add extra detail as an edit to the question. But anyway, it's not clear what you're trying to say. This code specifically would not cause the system to connect to a database, all it does is allow you to trap errors. Like I said, post some relevant code and also report any errors, and what behaviour you get.

Comment: After removing all instances of mysql from my machine, it is working. I don't know why ? but it is working

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why.. That's my problem too

Exception message :

> Authentication to host '' for user '' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user ''@'xxx' (using password: NO)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at MySql.Web.Common.SchemaManager.GetSchemaVersion(String connectionString)\r\n   at MySql.Web.Common.SchemaManager.CheckSchema(String connectionString, NameValueCollection config)\r\n   at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)

I suspect this happened after I installed mysql-community-5.7.20.0

Update : I uninstalled everything (mysql) just now and it's normal again